# .NET Caching - cache expires very early

Tags: c#, .net, caching, memorycache

I'm trying to use MemoryCache in .Net 4.5 to store an object for 1 month (absolute expiration - 1 month from when the cache is created).

**Problem** - 
The cache seems to expire within a day - sometimes within a few hours, in fact.

**Code Snippet**

```
// Setting the cache with absolute expiration time of 1 month:
string objName = "myObj";
MemoryCache memCache = MemoryCache.Default;
memCache.Add(tokenID, myObj, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMonths(1));

// Accessing the cache later
MemoryCache getCache = MemoryCache.Default;
getCache.Get(tokenID);
```

**Questions**

1. Am I setting the cache correctly?  I haven't seen any examples that use AddMonths(), but there are many that use AddDays() - should that matter though?
2. Is there a max amount of time that I could use for absolute expiration?  (I haven't come across any examples that set caches for more than 30 days, while not using infinite expiration time.)
3. What else could be causing the cache to expire so quickly?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Does the web server have a setting for shutting down the site on idle and is there constant traffic to stop that from happening?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen - My site's application pool settings has Idle Timeout = 5 minutes and Shutdown Time Limit = 90 seconds. Are you talking about any of those?

Comment: Yes, those exactly. That means if there are no requests to your site for five minutes the workers are being shut down which also removes everything from memory cache. Most likely that's causing the issues.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen - Ah!  That must be it.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the IIS AppPool setting you are using for your web application. Under **Advanced Settings**, there is a setting for **Idle Time-out (minutes)**. If your site is idle for longer that this period, the worker process is shut down.

[image]